# Copy/Inheritance of Ruby Matrix class (core/std lib)

Tags: ruby, inheritance, matrix, singleton

I tried to extend an existing Singleton class in Ruby, as an example the Matrix class.

My first *quick&dirty* solution was a monkey patch (reopen class and extend with functionality).

But I think, monkey patching in general isn't good, especially if someone tries to overwrite basic methods of core classes like in String, Integer, ...

Next step was to find out, how I can get a real hard copy of the Matrix class with a new name (like MatrixExt) which behaves as a standalone singleton.

```rb
MatrixExt = Matrix
```

didn't the job, as it results in:

```rb
MatrixExt.scalar(2,0)
=> Matrix[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

So I only get multiple names for same singleton. Not, what I want.

Same result with the `clone` and the `dup` methods.

Also class inheritance won't work:

```rb
class MatrixExt < Matrix
  # patches ...
end

MatrixExt.scalar(2,0)
=> Matrix[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

And that was the most confusing part, because in self defined classes it is possible to get an inherited class. (So, why the core/std lib classes work different?)

My current solution is to have a module with extension and then explicitly use `.extend` after initializing, like:

```rb
m = Matrix.scalar(2,0).extend(MatrixExtModule)
```

That is okay for now, but my question is:

**IS there another solution and -when yes- how to do it?**

*(No, copying the matrix.rb is not a good way, of course. ;o)*

**What I do wrong or where I think in a wrong way?**

Thanks in advance for any solution and/or food for thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug.

I've created an [issue on redmine.ruby-lang.org](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5307), which is the recommended thing to do to get these fixed.

I fixed the library, but I'm afraid it won't be available until Ruby 1.9.4.

Comment: And I thought it was an intended behavior. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at how `Matrix` is implemented, you'll notice that all the methods like `scalar`, `diagonal` etc. call the private `new` method, which will always return a new `Matrix` object (you don't override the methods, so Ruby will go look at the superclass implementation, where the implicit receiver of `new` is `self`, viz the `Matrix` class).

I guess your best bet is to wrap all your patches in a module and monkey patch `Matrix` that way.

Comment: Do you mean something like:

`class Matrix; extend MatrixExt; end`

Comment: (Mean: `... include MatrixExt ...`)

Comment: If you did `class MyObject; end; MyObject.new` you'd end up with a object with a class of `MyObject` rather than `Object`, even though you haven't implemented `MyObject.new`. How come that's different?

Comment: If you look at the C source of `Class#new` you'll see `obj = rb_obj_alloc(klass);`, meaning the returned object will be created with the current class before `initialize` gets called with `rb_obj_call_init(obj, argc, argv);`. In the `Matrix` example `new` is a private method which cannot be called with an explicit receiver, so `self` will always be `Matrix` when other methods like `diagonal` call it.