# Ruby Matrix set_element private?

Tags: ruby, matrix, ruby-1.9.2, access-specifier

When calling `set_element` on an instance of the Matrix class I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: private method ‘set_element’ called for Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]:Matrix
```

But `set_element` is listed under public instance methods in the documentation

[Matrix#set_element](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/classes/Matrix.html#M001125)

Also, set_element is an alias for [[]=(i, j, v)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/classes/Matrix.html#M001124) and using this method I get the following error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Doesn't make any sense, any help is appreciated.

Ruby 1.9.2 p180

Comment: You're not the first person surprised by Matrix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064902/copy-inheritance-of-a-ruby-singleton-class-core-std-lib . I don't know whether that question will help you though.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214367/using-ruby-1-9-2-with-rubymine-and-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect. If you look at the `matrix.rb` file from 1.9.1, you'll see this:

```
def []=(i, j, v)
  @rows[i][j] = v
end
alias set_element []=
alias set_component []=
private :[]=, :set_element, :set_component
```

So the three methods are there but they are explicitly set as private.

A bit of quick experimentation indicates that a lot of the methods in the documentation are, in fact, private. There is a big block of documentation at the top of the man page that lists what are, apparently, supposed to be the available methods; that list doesn't match the list that rdoc has generated so there is some confusion.

I get the impression that instances of Matrix are meant to be immutable just like Fixnum and Number.

Comment: There is a some discussion about this topic here http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/161792

Comment: @Ram: But I don't see any justification for the immutability of Matrix. Seems unnecessarily cumbersome to me. I suppose you could just copy `matrix.rb` and remove the `private` stuff, it looks like a simple array of arrays internally.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply make the setter functions public, possibly in your own class (or at Matrix itself):

```
class SetableMatrix < Matrix
  public :"[]=", :set_element, :set_component
end
```